# url rewriting by profile name

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with my URL rewriting. I want to get the url by username, like

```
 yourdomain.com/joshua
```

But the eror stay on 404.

.htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /eror/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /eror/403.php
ErrorDocument 500 /eror/403.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.recettes.nl/$1 [R,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^about$ about.php
RewriteRule ^recettes$ recettes.php
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^recept$ recept.php

RewriteRule ^login$ login.php
RewriteRule ^logout$ logout.php
RewriteRule ^register$ register.php
```

.profile.php

```
    if(!(isset($_GET['user']) && $_GET['user'] == $me['id'] || !isset($_GET['user'])) || isset($me)) {
    redirectByPermission('profiles');
}
function notempty($str) {
    return ($str != '');
}
if(isset($_GET['user'])) {
    $user_sql = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id');
    $user_sql->bindParam(':id', trim($_GET['user']), PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $user_sql->execute();
    $user = $user_sql->fetch();
}else{
    $user = $me;
}
```

Can some one help me with this and tell me what did I do wrong?

Comment: You just need: `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: @anubhava It give a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS eror.

Comment: This rule doesn't even redirect so you have some other conflicting rules.

Comment: Not in comments, edit your question and provide your code there.

Comment: Oké @anubhava is cool :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your full .htaccess as this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /eror/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /eror/403.php
ErrorDocument 500 /eror/403.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^(about|recettes|contact|login|logout|register)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: I have change it and thnx for the page pages :-) but by profile i still get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS, https://www.recettes.nl/joshua this is a test profile

Comment: No unless there is some other code or rule this code will not redirect to `/profile`

Comment: I have found the problem, i had a script that blocked not offline users you need to be logged when you want to see the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thnx, i'll try, i had already the rewriteEngine etc. but not the -d and -f.